# content/admin banner different language

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I can add images to various languages in OpenCart 1.5.6 version, this is how much you probably know pavcontentslider, I have the opportunity to do different languages but not text and image .. if anyone can help me I would be grateful. Thank you
Printscreen: http://postimg.org/image/v6nrcebrf/

code admin interface:

```php
    <?php
class ControllerModulePavcontentslider extends Controller {
    private $error = array(); 

    public function index() {   
        $this->language->load('module/pavcontentslider');
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {


            $this->request->post['pavcontentslider_module'][0]['banner_image'] =    $this->request->post['banner_image'];
            unset($this->request->post['banner_image']);


            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('pavcontentslider', $this->request->post);        

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('module/pavcontentslider', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $this->data['text_image_manager'] = $this->language->get('text_image_manager');
        $this->data['text_browse'] = $this->language->get('text_browse');
        $this->data['text_clear'] = $this->language->get('text_clear');         

        $this->data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $this->data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
        $this->data['text_content_top'] = $this->language->get('text_content_top');
        $this->data['text_content_bottom'] = $this->language->get('text_content_bottom');       
        $this->data['text_column_left'] = $this->language->get('text_column_left');
        $this->data['text_column_right'] = $this->language->get('text_column_right');

        $this->data['entry_title'] = $this->language->get('entry_title');
        $this->data['entry_width'] = $this->language->get('entry_width');
        $this->data['entry_height'] = $this->language->get('entry_height');

        $this->data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');
        $this->data['entry_layout'] = $this->language->get('entry_layout');
        $this->data['entry_position'] = $this->language->get('entry_position');
        $this->data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
        $this->data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');

        $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
        $this->data['button_add_module'] = $this->language->get('button_add_module');
        $this->data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');
        $this->data['no_image'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);        
        $this->data['entry_show_image'] = $this->language->get( 'entry_show_image' );
        $this->data['entry_module_title'] = $this->language->get( 'entry_module_title' );
        $this->data['tab_module'] = $this->language->get('tab_module_banner');
        $this->data['entry_image_navigator'] = $this->language->get( 'entry_image_navigator' );
        $this->data['entry_navigator_width'] = $this->language->get( 'entry_navigator_width' );
        $this->data['entry_navigator_height'] = $this->language->get( 'entry_navigator_height' );

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('module/pavcontentslider', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/pavcontentslider', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        $this->data['modules'] = array();
        $this->data['positions'] = array( 'mainmenu',
                                          'slideshow',
                                          'promotion',
                                          'content_top',
                                          'column_left',
                                          'column_right',
                                          'content_bottom',
                                          'mass_bottom',
                                          'footer_top',
                                          'footer_center',
                                          'footer_bottom'
        );

        $d = array('layout_id'=>'','position'=>'','status'=>'','sort_order'=>'1',
        'banner_image'=>array(),'width'=>940,'height'=>350,
        'image_navigator' => 0,
        'navimg_height'   =>97,
        'navimg_weight'   =>177,
        'text_interval'=>8000
        );

        $this->data['effects'] = array('slideUp','slideDown','slideLeft',
                    'slideRight','slideExpandUp','expandUp','fadeIn',
                    'expandOpen','bigEntrance','hatch','bounce',
                    'pulse','floating','tossing','pullUp','pullDown','stretchLeft','stretchRight'
                    );
        if (isset($this->request->post['pavcontentslider_module'])) {
            $this->data['modules'] = $this->request->post['pavcontentslider_module'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('pavcontentslider_module')) { 
            $this->data['modules'] = $this->config->get('pavcontentslider_module');
        }   
        if( !empty($this->data['modules']) ){
             $d = array_merge($d,$this->data['modules'][0]);            
        }
        $this->data['module'] = $d;
        if( $d['banner_image'] ){
            $tmp = array();$i=1;
            foreach( $d['banner_image'] as $key => $banner ){
                $banner['link'] = isset($banner['link'])?trim($banner['link']):"";
                $banner['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($banner['image'], 100, 100);
                $tmp[$i++] = $banner;
            }
             $d['banner_image'] = $tmp;
        }

        $this->data['banner_image'] = $d['banner_image'];
        $this->load->model('design/layout');
        $this->data['layouts'][] = array('layout_id'=>99999, 'name' => $this->language->get('all_page') );

        $this->data['layouts'] = array_merge($this->data['layouts'],$this->model_design_layout->getLayouts());


        $this->load->model('localisation/language');

        $this->data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();
        $this->document->addStyle('view/stylesheet/pavcontentslider.css');
        $this->template = 'module/pavcontentslider.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    public function typo(){

        if (isset($this->request->get['field'])) {
            $this->data['field'] = $this->request->get['field'];
        } else {
            $this->data['field'] = '';
        }


        $typoFile =     HTTP_CATALOG."catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/pavcontentslider.css";  
        if( file_exists( DIR_CATALOG ."view/theme/". $this->config->get('config_template')."/stylesheet/pavcontentslider.css" ) ){
            $typoFile =     HTTP_CATALOG."catalog/view/theme/". $this->config->get('config_template')."/stylesheet/pavcontentslider.css";   
        }
        $content = file_get_contents(  $typoFile );

        $this->data['typoFile'] = $typoFile; 
        $data = preg_match_all("#\.pav-caption\.([\w\-]+)\s*{\s*#", $content, $matches);


        $this->data['captions'] = array();

        if( isset($matches[1]) ){
            $this->data['captions']  = $matches[1];
        }   


        $this->template = 'module/pavcontentslider_typo.tpl';
        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/pavcontentslider')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        if( !isset($this->request->post['banner_image']) ){
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_missing_banner');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

home interface:

```php
<?php if( count($banners) ) { ?>
    <?php $id = rand(1,10);?>
   <div id="pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>" class="carousel slide pavcontentslider">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
             <?php foreach ($banners as $i => $banner) {  ?>
                <div class="item <?php if($i==0) {?>active<?php } ?>">
                    <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $banner['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if( isset($banner['layers']) && $banner['layers'] ) { ?>
                    <?php foreach( $banner['layers'] as $layer ) { ?>
                    <div class="pav-caption <?php echo $layer['effect']. " ".$layer['class'];?>" style="top:<?php echo (int)$layer['top']?>px;left:<?php echo (int)$layer['left']?>px">
                        <?php  echo $layer['caption'];?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>       
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php if( count($banners) > 1 ){ ?> 
        <a class="carousel-control left " href="#pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if( count($banners)  > 1 ) { ?>   
            <?php if( isset($setting['image_navigator']) && $setting['image_navigator'] ) { ?>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators thumb-indicators hidden-phone ">
            <?php foreach ( $banners as $j=>$item )  : ?>
                <li data-target="#pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>" data-slide-to="<?php echo $j;?>" class="<?php if($j==0) {?>active<?php } ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $item['image_navigator'];?>"/>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php foreach ( $banners as $j=>$item )  : ?>
                <li data-target="#pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>" data-slide-to="<?php echo $j;?>" class="<?php if($j==0) {?>active<?php } ?>"></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>



    </div>
    <?php if( count($banners) > 1 ){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $('#pavcontentslider<?php echo $id;?>').carousel({interval:8000});
    -->
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can someone help me?